# Why the intemReader is always sending the exact same value to CustomItemProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Why does the itemReader method is always sending the exact same file name to be processed in CustomItemProcessor?

As far as I understand, since I settup reader as @Scope and I set more than 1 in chunk, I was expecting the "return s" to move forward to next value from String array.

Let me clarify my question with a debug example in reader method:

1 - the variable stringArray is filled in with 3 file names (f1.txt, f2.txt and f3.txt)

2 - "return s" is evoked  with s = f1.txt

3 - "return s" evoked again before evoked customItemProcessor method (perfect untill here since chunk = 2)

4 - looking at s it contains f1.txt again (different from what I expected. I expected f2.txt)

5 and 6 - runs processor with same name f1.tx (it should work correctly if the second turn of "return s" would contain f2.txt)

7 - writer method works as expected (processedFiles contain twice the two names processed in customItemProcessor f1.txt and f1.txt again since same name was processed twice)

CustomItemReader

```
public class CustomItemReader implements ItemReader<String> {
       @Override
       public String read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,

                     ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
              String[] stringArray;

              try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get(env

                           .getProperty("my.path")))) {

                     stringArray = stream.map(String::valueOf)

                                  .filter(path -> path.endsWith("out"))

                                  .toArray(size -> new String[size]);

              }



              //*** the problem is here

              //every turn s variable receives the first file name from the stringArray

              if (stringArray.length > 0) {

                     for (String s : stringArray) {

                           return s;



                     }

              } else {

                     log.info("read method - no file found");

                     return null;
              }
              return null;
       }
```

CustomItemProcessor

```
public class CustomItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String , String> {

       @Override

       public String process(String singleFileToProcess) throws Exception {

              log.info("process method: " + singleFileToProcess);

              return singleFileToProcess;

       }

}
```

CustomItemWriter

```
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<String> {



       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory

                     .getLogger(CustomItemWriter.class);



       @Override

       public void write(List<? extends String> processedFiles) throws Exception {



              processedFiles.stream().forEach(

                           processedFile -> log.info("**** write method"

                                         + processedFile.toString()));



              FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();



              for (String s : processedFiles) {

                     Files.deleteIfExists(fs.getPath(s));

              }

       }
```

Configuration

```
@Configuration

@ComponentScan(...

@EnableBatchProcessing

@EnableScheduling

@PropertySource(...

public class BatchConfig {





       @Autowired

       private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;



       @Autowired

       private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;



       @Autowired

       private JobRepository jobRepository;



    @Bean

    public TaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {

        return new TaskExecutor() {

            @Override

            public void execute(Runnable task) {



            }

        };

    }



       //I can see the number in chunk reflects how many time customReader is triggered before triggers customProcesser     

       @Bean

       public Step step1(ItemReader<String> reader,

                     ItemProcessor<String, String> processor, ItemWriter<String> writer) {

              return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<String, String> chunk(2)

                           .reader(reader).processor(processor).writer(writer)

                           .allowStartIfComplete(true).build();



       }



       @Bean

       @Scope

       public ItemReader<String> reader() {

              return new CustomItemReader();



       }



       @Bean

       public ItemProcessor<String, String> processor() {

              return new CustomItemProcessor();



       }



       @Bean

       public ItemWriter<String> writer() {

              return new CustomItemWriter();



       }



       @Bean

       public Job job(Step step1) throws Exception {

              return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(step1).build();

       }
```

Scheduler

```
@Component

public class QueueScheduler {



       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory

                     .getLogger(QueueScheduler.class);



    private Job job;

    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;



    @Autowired

    public QueueScheduler(JobLauncher jobLauncher, @Qualifier("job") Job job){

        this.job = job;

        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;

   }

   @Scheduled(fixedRate=60000)

   public void runJob(){

          try{
       jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());

          }catch(Exception ex){

                 log.info(ex.getMessage());

          }

   }

}
```

Comment: Your reader is always going to return the first element of the array.

Comment: Michael Minella, thanks, I really appreciate when I see coments from you. I know the issue is related to my design, but how can I fix it? I understand I am doing nothing wrong with this design: itemReader collect the file names to be processed limited to chunck number, itemProcessor proccess one by one, itemWriter runs once deleting all files processed. Should I make chunk = 1 and send a collection/list of file names to itemWriter. Then in item writer I parse the collection/list to processes one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are relying on an internal loop to iterate over the items instead of letting Spring Batch do it for you by calling `ItemReader#read` multiple times.

What I'd recommend is changing your reader to the something like the following:

```
public class JimsItemReader implements ItemStreamReader {
   private String[] items;
   private int curIndex = -1;

   @Override
   public void open(ExecutionContext ec) {
       curIndex = ec.getInt("curIndex", -1);
       String[] stringArray;

       try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get(env.getProperty("my.path")))) {
           stringArray = stream.map(String::valueOf)
                               .filter(path -> path.endsWith("out"))
                               .toArray(size -> new String[size]);

        }
   }

   @Override
   public void update(ExecutionContext ec) {
       ec.putInt("curIndex", curIndex);
   }

   @Override
   public String read() {
       if (curIndex < items.length) {
           curIndex++;
           return items[curIndex];
       } else {
           return null;
       }
   }
}
```

The above example should loop through the items of your array as they are read.  It also should be restartable in that we're storing the index in the `ExecutionContext` so if the job is restarted after a failure, you'll restart where you left off.